# Spark dataframe saveAsTable not truncating data from Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark 2.1.0 and using Java SparkSession to run my SparkSQL.
I am trying to save a `Dataset<Row>` named `'ds'` to be saved into a Hive table named as `schema_name.tbl_name` using overwrite mode.
But when I am running the below statement

```
ds.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("header","true")
.option("truncate", "true")
.saveAsTable(ConfigurationUtils.getProperty(ConfigurationUtils.HIVE_TABLE_NAME));
```

the table is getting dropped after the first run. 
When I am rerunning it, the table is getting created with the data loaded.

Even using truncate option didn't resolve my issue. Does saveAsTable consider truncating the data instead of dropping/creating the table? If so, what is the correct way to do it in Java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reference to Apache JIRA for my question. Seems it is unresolved till now.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21036